# Can I open a file by its inode in a ext4 LUKS partition?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, ext4, file-recovery, luks

I have an **ext4 LUKS** partition where I "deleted" a file.
(I moved one into other: `mv /media/HDD/file1.txt /media/HDD/file2.txt` where both file1.txt and file2.txt already existed).

Files in the directory had consecutive inode numbers so I can guess the one I lost using `ls -il`, let's call it 12345678.

I tried `find -inum 12345678 -exec gedit {} \;` to open it (which works with the rest of files), but since it only searches in the directory it doesn't work with my lost file.

I tried **debugfs** (unlocking first: `udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb`) like this:

```
~$sudo debugfs /dev/sdb
debugfs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
debugfs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb contains a crypto_LUKS file system
debugfs:
```

The same happens if don't unlock the partition.

Why does it say "Bad magic number"?  How can I make it open the file?
Is there any other way to recover my file?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `find -inum 12345678` cannot find any deleted i-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried debugfs (unlocking first: udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb) like this: […]
>
> The same happens if don't unlock the partition. Why does it say "Bad magic number"?

LUKS doesn't change the way ext4 works. However, it changes where ext4 *is*.

Locking/unlocking a volume doesn't work like a toggle switch, it works like opening/closing a container. That is, when you "unlock" a LUKS volume, this doesn't change the original partition in any way – if /dev/sda1 contained encrypted LUKS data before, it'll still contain encrypted LUKS data afterwards, i.e. *not* ext4.

Instead the plaintext ext4 filesystem has to be accessed through a *new* device, usually `/dev/mapper/luks-something`, which filters read or written data through the LUKS encryption/decryption. So the correct command would be similar to:

```
sudo debugfs /dev/mapper/luks-whatever
```

(That aside, /dev/sdb is not a partition – it's the whole disk. Its partitions would have devices named /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdb2, and so on. It's relatively normal to have LUKS and/or ext4 directly on the whole disk, but that doesn't turn it into a partition.)

> Is there any other way to recover my file?

The [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_recovery) recommends the `ext4magic` tool.

The older `extundelete` tool may also work, although it's outdated and does not work with ext4 filesystems using metadata checksums.

Because your ext4 filesystem is inside LUKS, **all** such tools need to be run on the "mapper" device that 'udisksctl unlock' has created – not on the raw disk.

Comment: Thanks! It was at /dev/dm-0. And yes it was a whole disk, not a partition.